# Fetching distinct numeric value in ORACLE

Tags: php, oracle

I need a help on how to fetch distinct numeric value in ORACLE DB,

So i have this command

```
$proj_result = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT THICKNESS FROM COMPONENT_CUTTING WHERE PROJECT_NAME = ':projectName'");
        
        $getProject = $_GET['kode'];
        oci_bind_by_name($proj_result, ":projectName", $getProject);
        oci_execute($proj_result);

        echo '<SELECT name="provinsi" class="cmb" id="provinsi" onChange="DinamisProvinsi(this);">'.'<br>';
        echo '<OPTION VALUE=" ">'."- Select Thickness - ".'</OPTION>';

        while($row = oci_fetch_array($proj_result, OCI_BOTH))
             {
               $PROJ = $row[THICKNESS];
               echo "<OPTION VALUE='$PROJ'>$PROJ</OPTION>";
             }
```

and on the DB, row THICKNESS is NUMBER(38) which is an INTEGER datatype.

The problem is i cant pull all the distinct value in thickness relative to the project name. Its only showing 1 value. it should show at least 2 distinct value.

Am  I doing wrong in fetching the array ?

#### This is how the table looks .. http://jsbin.com/zaduseze/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should not put the single quotes around your **named parameters** . Remove them.

#### The right way..

```
$proj_result = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT THICKNESS FROM COMPONENT_CUTTING WHERE PROJECT_NAME = :projectName");
```

Comment: i removed the single quote but its still doesnt work

Comment: its okay with the ORACLE query console. only when i do OCI_FETCH_ARRAY. only same values that appear

Comment: Did you try with `$PROJ = $row['THICKNESS'];` you need to put quotes around here , else it will interpret as constant.

Comment: its still doesnt work tho i dont know why. here is the database looks like

http://jsbin.com/zaduseze/1/